# Programatically render a view in twig template

Tags: views, theming, 8

I want to render a particular view like Who's new,Recent content present in the core in my the twig template.Any suggestion on how to do it? I was thinking of using `views_embed_view()` because in Drupal 7 it used to work with php but I don't know how to do it Drupal 8. Thanks.
 For recent I tried following code:

`function template_preprocess_module(&$variables) {
  $variables['view_output']=views_embed_view("Recent content");
}`

and then in the twig template did this:

`{{ view_output}}`

Comment: This function still exists in Drupal 8 and takes the view name as the first parameter :)

Comment: @alexej_d I know this and tried to render in the twig template but it didn't worked for me. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: You are not using a machine name but the title you defined.

Comment: @holdnet `views_embed_view` must take a machine name and not title.

Answer (score 4):

Right, twig no longer allows you to execute php code anymore. This is a main feature of twig and its security model.

I'd suggest to use a preprocess function for now and there call the function or even better add a render array with `#type` view, with `#view_id` and `#display_id`, as it gives you caching as well.

On top, maybe add an issue against core. That sounds like a really helpful thing to have

Oh and `views_embed_view` should be changed to enable caching as well.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested by the contrib module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

Among other things, it will let you render views like this :

```
{{ drupal_view_result('view_name', 'view_display_name') }}
```

Cheat sheet : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x