# How to render two views in the same twig template

Tags: views, 8, theming

I want to render two views in the same twig template, but only one of them is rendered, and the second is always override with the same content as the first one.
I have a content type 'contacts' and when its nodes are displayed (full view) I want to render two views in the same page after the node fields. I use a twig template node--contacts.html.twig :

```
.....  node fields twig template .... 
{{ viewCalls }}  
....  
{{ viewAppointments }}  
....
```

And my `function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables)` in my .theme file:

```
....  
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('view_calls');
$view->setDisplay('default');
$view->setArguments(array($variables['node']->id()));
$view->setOffset(0);
$view->execute();
$variables['viewCalls'] = $view->render();

$view2 = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('view_appointments');
$view2->setDisplay('default');
$view2->setArguments(array($variables['node']->id()));
$view2->setOffset(0);
$view2->execute();
$variables['viewAppointments'] = $view2->render();
.....
```

As I said, the second view always shows the same content as the first. If I reverse the order of rendering, then the content is reverse too, and the one which is first rendered is the only one I see, and always two times. It is as `{{ viewCalls }}` and `{{ viewAppointments }}` always get the same content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you get the same content is due to the `#cache` property of the render array you get when you call the `render()` method.

Most specifically, by calling `setOffset()` earlier in your code, you are implicitly setting a cache key on the render array, (see [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AsetOffset/8.2.x)):

> ```
> $this->element['#cache']['keys'][] = 'offset:' . $offset;
> ```

This cache key setting, in combination with the `#theme` property of the render array (`views_view`), which is the same for both views, will result in getting a cached version of the first one when including the second one, since the [`#theme`] + [`#cache`][keys] combination is identical for both views.

To work around that you could:

1. Remove caching completely for these views, or
2. Avoid using `setOffset()`, or
3. Add more specific keys to the cache so that you have a different cache for each view. E.g.

   ```
   $variables['viewCalls']['#cache']['keys'] = 
     array_merge(
       $variables['viewCalls']['#cache']['keys'], 
       array('viewCalls')
     );
   ...
   $variables['viewAppointments']['#cache']['keys'] = 
     array_merge(
       $variables['viewAppointments']['#cache']['keys'],
       array('viewAppointments')
     );
   ```

I tested your case using the 3. option and it worked as expected, I think before resolving to using another module, you could try sticking to your original code and appropriately modifying the `#cache` property of both render arrays.

Good luck!

Comment: Great answer. I think the problem is that render() is not officially part of the Views API. Normally you should build a render element `'#type' => 'view'`, see [Programatically render a view in twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/162090/47547). Although I don't know how you can implement a custom offset dynamically through the Views API (if this is what the question is about, setting an offset other than 0).

Comment: Thanks very much. I works good. I have removed caching in my two views and setOffset and now two views are rendered right.

Comment: @briast – To remove caching actually is just some lukewarm medicine, it's not a fix to the underlying problem. Why would you remove caching and provide worse UX due to the resulting slower page speed when you could add your own cache keys as this brilliant in-depth answer shows you?

Comment: @briast, if you don't need `setOffset()` (which causes together with the unsupported `render()` this issue), simply render a view with: `['#type' => 'view', '#name' => $name, '#display_id' => $display_id, '#arguments' => $args]`

Comment: @leymannx - You're right. I've tried with the third options and it worked good. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your kind words 4k4 and leymannx : This was a riddle for me too, and the code provided by briast seems to be a way to go, when offset needs to be defined.

Answer (score 4):

Render two views in the same Twig template with the render element `view`:

```
$variables['viewCalls'] = [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => 'view_calls',
  '#display_id' => 'default',
  '#arguments' => [$variables['node']->id()],
];

$variables['viewAppointments'] = [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => 'view_appointments',
  '#display_id' => 'default',
  '#arguments' => [$variables['node']->id()],
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know a view could be render this way. I have changed it and it works good.

Comment: @briast Yes, this is an option too, doesn't allow you to control the offset though. It get's even easier with `views_embed_view()`, see https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/render-drupal-8-view-programmatically-render-arrays-ftw

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one typo in your code. Remove the space in `$variables['viewAppointments ']`.

---

Alternatively you could also use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak). Which will provide you a function you can use to place views directly in your templates.

```
{{ drupal_view('who_s_new', 'block_1', arg_1, arg_2, arg_3) }}`
```

> Twig Tweak is a small module which provides a Twig extension with some
>   useful functions and filters that can improve development experience.

Read the full guide on [Twig Tweak and Views](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/twig-tweak-and-views).

> Twig Tweak's `drupal_view()` method provide's access to embed views
>   within any Twig code, including dynamically from within each row of
>   another view. This feature provides an alternate method to accomplish
>   the nesting provided by the [Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, there was a typo but It was only in my answer. My code is right. Before posting my answer I read about the module you have mentioned. A quick review of this module didn't let me see how to pass arguments to the views, but I'll try it more in depth. Any way, I'm wondering why my code doesn't work and duplicate the view. It's a mystery.

Comment: @briast `{{ drupal_view('view_calls', 'default', node.id) }}`